# QuickBlox - How to get create custom query

Tags: quickblox

I need to get some Custom Objects but I need to check if two fields contain the value I pass.

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[parameters setValue:@"188888" forKey:@"user_id"];
[parameters setValue:@"188888" forKey:@"sent_to"];

[QBCustomObjects objectsWithClassName:@"Messages" extendedRequest:parameters delegate:self];
```

What I need is to check if the first parameter OR the second parameter are satisfied. With the code above I get a response as if a query was build like "user_id = 188888 AND sent_to = 188888".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator OR is not supported in Custom Objects API yet.

I propose you to make 2 separates queries and than merge 2 results in client application

Comment: Thanks Igor! I found a solution for that! It would be good to have this operator soon!

Comment: Sure, i have already wrote to QuickBlox server team about this. Anyway this is great idea we think